# Is there a way to combine two keys to make one? python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, key

I have keys `Name`, `Id` and `Major`. Is there a way to make the values of `Name` and `Id` the key with `Major` being the value in a dictionary?

```
Name     Id       Major
Joe      001      Math
Kyle     002      Coms
Lisa     003      Engr
Mia      004      Art
Nick     005      Engr
Olga     006      Math

{'Joe 001': Math, 'Kyle 002': Coms, 'Lisa 003': Engr, etc.}
```

I'm trying to do this from an excel file so I dont want to manually input all the names I'm practicing with. Is there a way to combine keys?

Could you help or link me to something that may help?

Comment: Keys must be immutable; create tuple keys to hold both values. You could always concat the strings as you have but that removes a definitive breaker between the two values (whitespace delimiting is not foolproof)

Comment: The question already seems to contain a suggestion: Concatenate the two strings into a single string and use that as the key, possibly with some extra character as internal separator within the key. E.g. `Joe` and `001` --> `Joe 001`.

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question, but am I able to do this by referencing the column label names? so as not to do it manually

Comment: We are assuming this is a pandas dataframe? You haven't added the tag. Off the top of my head, you could just iterate the rows in the DF.values and build your dictionary that way to make the tuple key. I don't know if this can be done with `to_dict()` but I'm not sure you're getting a speed hit with `iterrows` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data is in pandas.Dataframe, you can alter the data and use [pandas.DataFrame.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html). For example:

```
df['Key']=df['Name']+df['Id'] #combine the two columns you want to make keys
df=df.drop(['Name','Id'],axis=1).set_index('Key').T.to_dict('list')
```

After combining the two columns, I set Key as index then transpose. This will get rid of the column names from index. Then I convert it to dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You can make desired list by list comprehention:

```
d2=[
{'Name': 'Joe', 'Id': '001',  'Major': 'Math'},
{'Name': 'Kyle', 'Id': '002',  'Major': 'Coms'}
]
d3={x['Name']+" "+x['Id'] : x['Major'] for x in d2}

print (d3)

#{'Joe 001': 'Math', 'Kyle 002': 'Coms'}
```

Answer (score 2):

As user roganjosh mentioned, the best way is to create tuple keys.

This is done by looping over your rows and adding to a dict with this.

```
my_dict = {}
for row in rows:
    my_dict[(row.Name, row.Id)] = row.Major
```

**DO NOT** just append them as strings. Since Name and Id are unique upon each other, there is no guarantee that the concatenation of them is also unique. EX. Name:joe0 Id:01 and Name:joe Id:001 are the same when concatenated. Save them as tuples to be safe.